# How to generate a list of different handlebars partials?

Tags: html, arrays, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm using handlebars.js with [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble).

I have a list of partials (which are svgs):
icon-blue.hbs, icon-red.hbs, icon-white.hbs etc

I would like loop through an array and generate a different partial for each index.

I have the following in my JSON:

```
"list": [
 {
  "color": "red",
  "val": "Lorem ipsum"
 },
 {
  "color": "blue",
  "val": "Lorem ipsum"
 },
 {
  "color": "white",
  "val": "Lorem ipsum"
 }
]
```

then in index.hbs I want to do something like this:

```
{{#myData}}
  {{#each list}}
    {{> icon-{{color}} }} --> I know this isn't possible, so what can I do instead?
    <span>{{val}}</span>
  {{/each}}
{{/myData}}
```

Is there any way to do this? or any other way to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In handlebars you'll need to use a helper to join or concat variables.

You can add a helper to `assemble` like this:

```
app.helper('icon', function(name) {
  return 'icon-' + name;
});
```

Then you can use the built in partial helper and handlebars [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions):

```
{{#myData}}
  {{#each list}}
    {{partial (icon color)}}
    <span>{{val}}</span>
  {{/each}}
{{/myData}}
```

Comment: @anita I saw your suggested edits. My answer is in regards to the current version of assemble. If you're using `grunt-assemble`, you should make another answer specifying that with the content of your edits (I think that it makes sense for `grunt-assemble`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess (I've never used handlebars), but I think this would make sense in javascript:

```
{{#each list}}
    {{'icon-' + this.color}}
    <span>{{val}}</span>
{{/each}}
```